# How to hide labels per default in a python dash graph?

Tags: python, dashboard, plotly-dash

Say I have a simple graph like that:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),

    html.Div(children='''
        Dash: A web application framework for Python.
    '''),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure={
            'data': [
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 1, 2], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'SF'},
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 4, 5], 'type': 'bar', 'name': u'Montréal'},
            ],
            'layout': {
                'title': 'Dash Data Visualization'
            }
        }
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

The code produces the following graph:

[image]

If I click on one of the two labels "SF" or "Montréal", this particular label is greyed out and removed from the graph. Is there a way to grey out labels by default? I would like to plot a graph with a lot of labels, but it looks like a mess. But I also do not want to exclude any data. A nice way to achieve a clean look but also retain the completeness of the data would be to hide these labels per default. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats quite easy to achieve in plotly.

You have to add `'visible': 'legendonly'` to your trace.

Example:

```
'data': [
        {'x': [1, 2, 3],
         'y': [4, 1, 2],
         'type': 'bar',
         'name': 'SF',
         'visible': 'legendonly'
         },
        {'x': [1, 2, 3],
         'y': [2, 4, 5],
         'type': 'bar',
         'name': u'Montréal'
         },
    ],
```